# Probability of hitting target after 1 shot from 2 shooters

Tags: probability

Two shooters shoot a target. The known probability to hit the target of the first and second shooter are $0.70$ and $0.80$ respectively. What is the probability that the target is hit after one shot from both shooters?

I tried

$$P_1= 0.7$$

$$P_2=0.8$$

$$P=P_1+P_2-P_1P_2=0.94=94\%$$

But it seems too simple and probability is too big so i'm not sure i'm on the right way?

Comment: I think that you have the right answer

Comment: (Assuming that the two shots are independent.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

1) The probability that the target is missed by BOTH shooters is : $p=0.3\times 0.2$

2) Your answer is correct.