# How many shots need to get $0.99$ probability?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

The shooter hits a target with $0.8$ probability with a single shot.

> How many shots are needed to get $0.99$ probability that the target is hit ?

Comment: What have you tried?  And here is a hint: the probability that you miss one shot is $0.2$, the probability that you miss two shots is $(0.2)^2$, the probability that you miss three is $(0.2)^3$ (why is this the case?).

Comment: Is it correct to use Binomial probability. To find N : 0.99 = C(n, n-1) * 0.8 ^ 1 * (1-0.8)^n-x. To prove my answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Probability of hitting target after 1 shot from 2 shooters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522747/probability-of-hitting-target-after-1-shot-from-2-shooters)

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve $$1-0.2^n\ge 0.99$$ which is equivalent to $$0.01\ge 0.2^n$$ Taking the logarithm leads to $$n\ge \frac{\ln(0.01)}{\ln(0.2)}$$ Rounded up, we get $n\ge 3$

Answer (score 1):

The chance of $n$ misses is $(\frac{1}{5})^n$. For what $n$ is this smaller than $\frac{1}{100}$? Logarithms might help, or note that $5^3=125 > 100$...